# .next() with .is(:hidden) not working

Tags: jquery

So I have a script that goes like:

```
$(".contenttitle,.contenttitle_half").click (function(){
     $(this).next().stop().toggle(); 
    $goran = $(this);
      if ($(this).next().stop().is(':hidden')) { do something }
```

and it's working. But the new script which should not `onclick`, but `onload` test if element is hidden isnt working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".contenttitle").next().is(':hidden')) { DO SOMETHING }
```

and this one isn't working for some reason. If I test `$(".contenttitle").next()` with  console, it shows next elements, which means only `.is(:hidden)` isn't working.

Comment: Is there any chance that the element in fact just isn't hidden?

Comment: Yeah, to elaborate on Nikos question, do you have an onready function that hides these elements in the first place?

Comment: Working fine for me, [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3UAce/)

Comment: Yes, its saved in DB. But during the opening of page, these hidden elements are showed for like 0.1s, then they hide. Can this be a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more the 1 .contenttitle on the page try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contenttitle').each(function() {
       if ($(this).next(':hidden').length > 0) { DO SOMETHING }
    });
...
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, thats it, its working now.
But why isnt it working with just empty next() selector, if this function is testing if next element is visible ( .length > 0 )

if ($(this).next().length > 0)

Comment: I tested now with .is('hidden') and its also working, which means that problem was with each. Again thanks Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a selector in next:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if ($(".contenttitle").next(':hidden').length > 0) { DO SOMETHING }
```